# Find the protected method after inheritance in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There is an ApplicationClass class with the CustomMethod method:

```
public class ApplicationClass : MonoBehaviour 
{
    protected void CustomMethod()
    {
        //any code
    }
}
```

From ApplicationClass, NewClass is inherited:

```
public class NewClass : ApplicationClass 
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        ApplicationController.ScriptAdd(this);
    }
}
```

NewClass at creation creates itself in array scriptArr of class ApplicationController.
And ScriptCustomMethod calls the necessary methods on demand:

```
public class ApplicationController : MonoBehaviour
{

    private static MonoBehaviour[] scriptArr;

    public static void ScriptAdd(MonoBehaviour script)
    {
        Array.Resize(ref scriptArr, scriptArr?.Length + 1 ?? 1);
        scriptArr[scriptArr.Length - 1] = script;
    }

    public static void ScriptCustomMethod(string methodName, object[] arg)
    {
        if (scriptArr == null) return;

        for (int i = 0; i < scriptArr.Length; i++)
        {
            var dynMethod = scriptArr[i].GetType().GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            dynMethod?.Invoke(scriptArr[i], arg);
        }
    }
}
```

You need to call CustomMethod from NewClass using ScriptCustomMethod:

```
private void Update()
{
    ApplicationController.ScriptCustomMethod("CustomMethod", new object[] { });
}
```

But I can not find it and call it using various combinations of BindingFlags.
If the CustomMethod is moved from ApplicationClass to NewClass, then the above code works.

Comment: Have you tried `BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy`?

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: I have a feeling that because you are adding it as a `MonoBehavior` and not a `NewClass`, that it isn't searching the derived class. Try just using the array `NewClass` there and see if it works. It may be better if you keep a list of `Action` that you can call with the parameters instead of trying to invoke through reflection.

Comment: Thank you for directing me to the right track.
It was necessary to do so:
private static ApplicationClass[] scriptArr;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use one of the [overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethod?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads):

```
typeof(C).GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy, null, new Type[] { typeof(ParentClass) }, null)).Invoke(null, parameter));
```

or you can create a public method in NewClass which will call the protected method in base class.

Else, scriptArr is of type MonoBehaviour. Are you sure MonoBehaviour has the method? Can you add the same method to MonoBehaviour instead of ApplicationClass or try creating an array of ApplicationClass.

Comment: Your method also does not work. 
I'll have to create a public method. Thought could be done without it.

Comment: scriptArr is of type MonoBehaviour. Are you sure MonoBehaviour has the method? Can you add the same method to MonoBehaviour instead of ApplicationClass

Comment: Thank you for directing me to the right track.
It was necessary to do so:
private static ApplicationClass[] scriptArr;